# How can i replace little part of profilepic url path in all documents by running single query in mongodb

Tags: replace, mongodb-query

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bd6ed6a49ba281f5c54f185"), 
        "AvatarSet" : {
            "Avatar" : [
                {
                    "IsPrimaryAvatar" : true, 
                    "ProfilePictureUrl" : "https://blob.blob.core.windows.net/avatarcontainer/avatardba36759-3e8e-4666-bc2b-e53ffb527716.jpeg?version=8b1b58b3-94f8-4608-b4db-05746eea8bfe"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Here I need to Replace only `https://blob.blob.core.windows.net` to every candidateID present in the database please help me how to write MongoDB Query for this?

I'm using Query but it's not working

```
db.getCollection("candidate-staging")
.find({},{"AvatarSet":[0]})..forEach(function(e) {
    e.ProfilePictureUrl= e.ProfilePictureUrl.replace("https://blob.blob.core.windows.net", "https://blob123.blob.core.windows.net");
    db.candidate-staging.save(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your script is that the ProfilePictureUrl is not properly referred, using dot notation like in the example below should solve the problem.

In your code `e.ProfilePictureUrl` points to a missing field in the top level document, while `doc.AvatarSet.Avatar[0].ProfilePictureUrl` in the following example points to the ProfilePictureUrl field for the first element in the Avatar array under the AvatarSet field from the main document.

```
db.test.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.AvatarSet.Avatar[0].ProfilePictureUrl= doc.AvatarSet.Avatar[0].ProfilePictureUrl.replace("https://blob.blob.core.windows.net", "https://blob123.blob.core.windows.net");     
  db.test.save(doc); 
});
```

Local test:

```
mongos> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bdb5e3c553c271478a9a006"), "AvatarSet" : { "Avatar" : [ { "IsPrimaryAvatar" : true, "ProfilePictureUrl" : "https://blob.blob.core.windows.net/avatarcontainer/avatardba36759-3e8e-4666-bc2b-e53ffb527716.jpeg?version=8b1b58b3-94f8-4608-b4db-05746eea8bfe" } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bdb5e3e553c271478a9a007"), "AvatarSet" : { "Avatar" : [ { "IsPrimaryAvatar" : true, "ProfilePictureUrl" : "https://blob.blob.core.windows.net/avatarcontainer/avatardba36759-3e8e-4666-bc2b-e53ffb527716.jpeg?version=8b1b58b3-94f8-4608-b4db-05746eea8bfe" } ] } }

mongos> db.test.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
 doc.AvatarSet.Avatar[0].ProfilePictureUrl= doc.AvatarSet.Avatar[0].ProfilePictureUrl.replace("https://blob.blob.core.windows.net", "https://blob123.blob.core.windows.net");    
 db.test.save(doc); });
mongos> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bdb5e3c553c271478a9a006"), "AvatarSet" : { "Avatar" : [ { "IsPrimaryAvatar" : true, "ProfilePictureUrl" : "https://blob123.blob.core.windows.net/avatarcontainer/avatardba36759-3e8e-4666-bc2b-e53ffb527716.jpeg?version=8b1b58b3-94f8-4608-b4db-05746eea8bfe" } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bdb5e3e553c271478a9a007"), "AvatarSet" : { "Avatar" : [ { "IsPrimaryAvatar" : true, "ProfilePictureUrl" : "https://blob123.blob.core.windows.net/avatarcontainer/avatardba36759-3e8e-4666-bc2b-e53ffb527716.jpeg?version=8b1b58b3-94f8-4608-b4db-05746eea8bfe" } ] } }
```

Comment: [js] TypeError: doc.AvatarSet.Avatar[0] is undefined  : its showing error

Comment: You need to validate that the first element of the array exists. Otherwise you will get an error. Also note that in my example I have changed the name of the function parameter using `doc` instead of `e`.

Please note that this is a different issue unrelated to your original question.

Comment: it's related to original Question only I just copied your answer so I change doc in place of e I tried different way still i get undefined but your answer is  right why i get undefined i don't know e.AvatarSet.Avatar[0].ProfilePictureUrl.ProfilePictureUrl is undefined still getting i'm using robo3t to excute a script

Answer (score 0):

In this code contains objects of an array of the object  In this code reach `AvatarSet`Array points to a missing field in the top-level document because we need to access objects within the Another Array so we need to write another loop for 'Avatar' Array like `e.AvatarSet.Avatar.forEach` its really works. it's work for me.

```
db.getCollection("test").find({}).forEach(function(e,i) {
    e.AvatarSet.Avatar.forEach(function(url, j) {
        url.ProfilePictureUrl = url.ProfilePictureUrl.replace("https://blob.blob.core.windows.net", "https://blob123.blob.core.windows.net");
        e.AvatarSet.Avatar[j] = url;
    });
    db.getCollection("test").save(e);
    eval(printjson(e));
})
```

thanks!! manfonton and stackoverflow